# Simplified Crypto Libraries for iOS

Tags: ios, security, cryptography, libraries

I've worked with Java cryptography for many years.  Now, we have a requirement to write an iOS application that will send encrypted payloads from the mobile device to a Java service.  I've begun working with the iOS crypto support (CommonCrypto, etc.) and have found it a bit more difficult.  The JCE has a very clean, concise API, so I've clearly gotten spoiled.  In contrast, iOS cryptography is a far more difficult API to work with.

Are there any simplified crypto libraries or wrappers around CommonCrypto that provide a more concise API?  In particular, we need:

- Key generation (both symmetric and asymmetric)
- Encryption/decryption of data
- Digital signatures (SHA1withRSA, for example)
- Hashing
- RSA, 3DES, and AES support

I know I've seen a sample class or two that wraps AES encryption, for example.  I'm looking for something a bit richer and more full-featured.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use openSSL inside your iOS app, for ease of use you can use the [SSCrypto library](http://septicus.com/products/opensource/) by septicus.

From the septicus site:

> SSCrypto.framework provides a simple wrapper around OpenSSL library
>   functions for encryption, decryption (both symmetric and RSA) and
>   checksums. It also encodes and decodes base64 data and can generate
>   both private and public RSA keys. A test tool is included in the
>   project. Click here to see the [main.m](http://septicus.com/products/opensource/main.html) file that comes with SSCrypto
>   for examples of it's use.

Comment: Does SSCrypto build for iOS?  I downloaded the project and took a look at it.  It definitely seems like what I need, but there are only build configurations for Macs.  No iOS devices.

Comment: We just did add the .h and .m file to our project, the iOS build of our project did the rest...